# Graph Theory: Prove that G must be connected

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $ \frac 1 2 (n-1)(n-2)+1$ edges. Prove that $G$ must be connected.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried proving it? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

[Edited - thanks to M. Vinay who spotted the initial mistake!]

Suppose for contradiction that the graph is disconnected. Then it is possible to partition the graph into two subgraphs (disconnected from one another), with $k$ vertices and $n- k$ vertices respectively.

By a simple counting argument, you should be able to show that these two subgraphs can have at most $\frac 1 2 k(k-1)$ and $\frac 1 2 (n-k)(n-k-1)$ edges respectively.

It then remains to check that, for any value of $k$ between $1$ and $n-1$,
$$ \frac 1 2 k(k-1) + \frac 1 2 (n-k)(n-k-1) < \frac 1 2 (n-1)(n-2) + 1,$$ 
which would give a contradiction.

Comment: Is it easy to prove that inequality? I've been trying and the only way I can see right now is the boring and obvious one (expand the difference of the LHS and RHS, cancel some common terms, then rearrange to get an obviously positive term).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the difference comes out to be $(k - 1)(n - k - 1) + 1$, and since $k < n$, this is indeed always positive. Note: I cancelled out the $2$ in the denominators of the LHS and the RHS.

Comment: @M.Vinay Yes, in fact $(k-1)(n-k-1)+1$ is the difference without cancelling the factor of $2$ -  I checked on mathematica. Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh, right. I cancelled another $2$ (from the numerator) in later step. The explains it.